# How to write rownum in where clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am quite new to Postgres database. I have one query:

```
select offer_id, offer_date
  from CMS_OFFER
 where ROWNUM < 300
```

which executes in Oracle but in Postgres it is not excuted.
I tried with row_number() also. It is not able to execute. Please help me: how I can achieve this?

Comment: Ah - the (dis)advantages of using proprietary extensions to SQL.  They don't move with you when you switch DBMS.  Oracle's ROWNUM is peculiar to it, and not necessarily available elsewhere, unless the 'elsewhere' happens to emulate Oracle.

Comment: Not that there is a non-proprietary way to do this...

Comment: @Thilo: According to the PostgreSQL docs SQL:2008 introduced the `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` syntax. So there is a standard way. But I doubt that Oracle supports it.

Answer (score 7):

While not exactly the same as Oracle's ROWNUM, Postgresql has LIMIT:

```
select offer_id,offer_date from CMS_OFFER  LIMIT 299
```

The difference is that ROWNUM is applied before sorting, and LIMIT after sorting (which is usually what you want anyway).

Answer (score 2):

```
select offer_id,offer_date from CMS_OFFER limit 299
```